# Is there a risk when I recieve unknown tokens?

Tags: phantom, security

Someone sent to my phantom wallet some AmaraGold Brown tokens a few months ago.

I don't know the person nor the tokens.

Is there a risk if I have those tokens on my wallet and, if so, what do I need to do?

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Hi Alix! This site is about Solana programming. For DeFI and NFT questions I would try Reddit.

Answer (score 2):

Getting random tokens in your wallet is not avoidable and is not a security risk. Anyone can send you tokens since your wallet address is public. You need to be carful though not to click on any links on NFTs though. They may link you to scam sites which may be potentially malicious.

Also depending on the wallet you use loading the images of NFTs can in some cases track some information about your ip address.

You can also burn tokens and get some sol back that is used to save these tokens on chain. Phantom wallet for example has this feature. And you can also mark them as spam and hide them if they are bothering you.